# Modify H.264 Level in MP4 stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, mp4

I have 1000+ videos with wrong Level information, and hence do not play on some devices. They are H.264 baseline with aac audio in mp4 container. I want to correct them but avoid re-encoding. Am I right in assuming that this is possible and will be faster? How do I identify the level_idc bits in the streams? Will all streams have them in the same location? I expect this to be in just one place in the stream, is this assumption correct?
Update: I came across a windows executable [link](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/H264-AVC-Level-Editor) that claims to do this. I want to be able to do this commandline on unix, so I can script it.

More Updates: As per Roman's answer below. I dug up MP4 syntax and found that Profile and Level information are part of `avcC` atom under `stsd`. I could see that level was set to `1E`, I corrected it to `1F`. Before: `61 76 63 43 01 42 C0 1E FF E1 00 19 67 42 C0 1E
D9`
After: `61 76 63 43 01 42 C0 1F FF E1 00 19 67 42 C0 1E
D9` with that the MediaInfo changed to:

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Muxing mode                              : Container profile=Baseline@3.1
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1mn 4s
Bit rate                                 : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.109
Stream size                              : 22.7 MiB (92%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 120 r2151 a3f4407
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
```

It introduced a Muxing mode parameter with level `3.1` but alas this stream did not play on the device either. How do I correct the level indicated in `Format Profile` Is this possible without re-encoding?

Comment: What level is set now and what level is needed? Can you post mediainfo of some files?

Comment: Its set to 3.0 and I want it to be 3.1, They are all 720p videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that level is there on format descriptor, and also possibly duplicated on the payload itself. If you don't care about actual integrity of descriptor itself and the payload/encoding (I suppose it's fine to raise level, it might be not okay to lower it though), it is possible to change level without reencoding video.

More than that It is possible to do it both ways, by locating box that holding video track descriptor and patching the level by right there - you won't need FFmpeg, you rather access bytes directly and MP4 format is perhaps simple enough to do it from plain code.

Or, you need to re-multiplex the tracks changing format on the way. Demultiplexers and multiplexers don't do checks to tell whether this level value is acceptable or not, so patching it as a part of re-multiplexing with FFmpeg is workable. Any sample FFmpeg code that does writing to MP4 without re-encoding would be a good start (your task will be to update byte array pointed to by `extradata` field before opening `AVFormatContext`).

Comment: From my understanding of H.264, It consists of packets that can be independently decodable, So each of the packets will have a level_idc in the header. If I use option 1, directly modifying the bits in mp4, I may have to do it in multiple places in the stream?

Comment: `level_idc` might appear with every frame, but normally it only appears with key frames only, and it's optional as well. You might want to patch frames too, of course, and it depends on your task: if some software or system rejects the file because of H.264 level, it might only look at format descriptor to elaborate the rejection, and patching descriptor is sufficient.

Comment: I patched the descriptor. I found avcC under stsd and changed the level from 1E to 1F. The mediainfo run on this files gives me: `VideoID : 1 Format : AVC Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec Format profile : Baseline@L3.0 Format settings, CABAC : No Format settings, ReFrames : 3 frames Muxing mode : Container profile=Baseline@3.1` But it still does not play on the samsung TV. Where does mediainfo get the other profile from? The TV does seem to care for the container profile.

Comment: What makes you think it's level in first place that make the files fail to play?

Comment: Because when I re-encode with the same parameters, but ensure the level is set correctly it plays.

Comment: mediainfo still gets Format profile : Baseline@L3.0 after the correcting the level in avcC, Is it possible to correct that without re-encoding?

Comment: The second `1E` in your quote is also level indication (a part of SPS), you need to patch it as well then. I still doubt that level is the only thing that prevents the file from playing, esp. that *increasing* it fixes the issues.

Comment: Or even the better idea would be to encode the same file with 3.0 and 3.1 and compare descriptors for other differences.

Comment: Ok, Found a solution, searched for all patterns of `42 C0 1E` and replaced them with `42 C0 1F` throughout the file and voila the file plays! Thanks @Roman for all the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, a big credit goes to @Roman for helping me figuring this out. 
Find the Profile and Level after avcC atom in the `mp4` bitstream, in my case this was `42 C0 1E` , Baseline@L3.0, I wanted the level to be `3.1`. To do this find all occurrences of `42 C0 1E` in the stream and replace `1E` with `1F`. I found about 8-10 such occurrences. And now you have Baseline@L3.1. This can be verified using `mediainfo`. I think this is necessary because h.264 is encoded as a bunch of packets, and each of them have SPS header with profile and level information.